# My second endpoint doesn't work for node-js API, why?

Tags: javascript, node.js, endpoint

Trying to make my first API. It was going well, except for some reason my second route, `app.route('characters/:characterId')` isn't working. None of the endpoints work, even though the first route, `app.route('/characters')` works fine. I've been on this for like an hour and I have no idea what's going on.

Help?

Here is the controller

```
'use strict';
    
    var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Character = mongoose.model('Characters')
    
    exports.list_all_characters = function(req, res) {
        Character.find({}, function(error, character){
            if (error)
            res.send(error);
            res.json(character)
        })
    }
    
    exports.create_a_character = function(req, res) {
        var new_character = new Character(req.body);
        new_character.save(function(error, character){
            if (error)
            res.send(err);
            res.json(character);
        });
    };
    
    exports.get_a_character = function(req, res) {
        Character.findbyId(req.params.characterId, function(error, character){
            if(error)
            res.send(err);
            res.json(character);
        });
    }
    
    exports.update_a_character = function(req, res) {
        Character.findByIdAndUpdate({_id: req.params.characterId}, req.body, {new: true}, function(error){
            if (error)
            res.send(error);
            res.json(character);
        });
    };
    
    exports.delete_a_character = function(req, res) {
        Character.remove({_id: req.params.characterId}, function(error, character) {
                if(error) {
                res.send(error);
                res.json({message: 'Character Deleted'});
            }
        })
    }
```

Here is the router

```
'use strict';
    
    module.exports = function(app) {
        var characterList = require('../controllers/characterListController')
    
    app.route('/characters')
    .get(characterList.list_all_characters)
    .post(characterList.create_a_character);
    
    app.route('characters/:characterId')
    .get(characterList.get_a_character)
    .put(characterList.update_a_character)
    .delete(characterList.delete_a_character);
    };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a /

```
app.route('/characters/:characterId')
```

Comment: Wow, I'm dumb. It worked. Having some issues with postman timing out but the endpoints work now. Thank you!

Comment: No problem! It happens to everyone no exception XD